# Where is the equivalence of the relation used in the construction of the numbers?

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, real-numbers, equivalence-relations

Given $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,...\}$, the set of integers is defined by
$$\mathbb Z=\Big\{\{(x,y)\mid (x,y)R(a,b)\}\mid (a,b)\in\mathbb N\times \mathbb N\Big\},$$
where $R$ is the binary relation defined by
$$(a,b)R(c,d)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad a+d=b+c.$$

When this construction is presented, usually the first step is to prove (or, at least to mention) that $R$ is an equivalence relation. The same is true about the construction of $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$.

Questions:

- Why do we have to know that the relations used to construct the numbers are equivalence relations?
- Are the reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity really needed in the construction? Or are these properties just a coincidence?

Comment: We want to be able to say when one integer is "equal to" another integer, noting that the representation of that integer may vary.  Being "equal to" we want to have the same properties of the prototypical "equal to" which is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 6):

Equivalence relations are a generalisation of the identity. Their properties are reflecting *exactly* that.

Now, why are we even using them? Well, we have a structure given to us, e.g. $\Bbb N$, and we want to define $\Bbb Z$ as the closure of $\Bbb N$ under additive inverses. We observe that we can think about an element of $\Bbb Z$ as the "difference between two natural numbers". Only that there is no difference operation, we only have $+$. So we want to understand how would the difference behave, given $+$.

We are smart, and we know what we're looking for, we want to identify differences, i.e. $a-b=c-d$. But we understand that $x-y=z$ should be the same as $x=z+y$, and so we get $a+d=c+b$. And this defines the equivalence relation on $\Bbb{N\times N}$ that we're looking for.

Now, because we were smart and used $+$ to define $-$, we can show that the operations of $+$ and $\cdot$, and the order $\leq$, all of which are defined in terms of $+$,  will in fact extend to $\Bbb{N\times N}/{\sim}$, where $\sim$ is our equivalence relation, under the obvious embedding $n\mapsto[(n,0)]_{\sim}$.

And this understanding extends to $\Bbb{Q,R,C}$, and other type of constructions of this sort.

Comment: Couldn't $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N/\sim$ be defined even if $\sim$ was a relation that is not an equivalence relation? If so, in the context of the construction of the numbers, why we have to remark that it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive?

Comment: Isn't the relation $a+d=c+b$ primarily designed to encode subtraction? If so, couldn't we say that it is a coincidence that it is an equivalence relation and that this property is never used in the construction of the numbers?

Comment: (1) What does $X/{\sim}$ even mean if $\sim$ is *not* an equivalence relation? If it's a partition, then $\sim$ *was in fact* an equivalence relation, since we have a correspondence between partitions and equivalence relations given by $R\mapsto X/R$. (2) Yes, as I said, $a+d=c+b$ *is* encoding subtraction, and since it is meant to **identify different pairs as being "almost the same"** it is ***necessarily*** an equivalence relation, as implied by the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: Isn't the set $\{\{x\mid x R a\}\mid a\in X\}$ well defined for any relation $R$?  Why does it have to be a partition?

Comment: Yes, but we use the notation $X/{\sim}$ *exclusively* for equivalence relations. If you have $R$ which is not an equivalence relation, and you want to define some operation on $\{\{x\mid x\mathrel{R}a\}\mid a\in X\}$ based on an operation on $X$, if $R$ is not an equivalence relation the the operation is either not well-defined, or not defined everywhere.